# Least cost path from visibility

Tags: arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, viewshed, cost-path

I use ArcGIS 10.1 and I am dealing with viewshed and least cost path analysis. I would like to generate a path on the basis of a cost surface taking into account the viewshed data as indicated in the paper "On applying viewshed analysis for determining least-cost paths on Digital Elevation Models" by Stucky and Lee. In order to do that the authors say:

> To support the computation of the various least-cost paths discussed in this paper, two grids of visibility information should be calculated. The first is a general viewgrid (VG) that records for each cell the number of cells visible. The second is a dominance viewgrid (VD) that holds for each cell the number of cells from which the cell is visible. Both grids are constructed by calculating intervisibility between grid cells using the LoS algorithm. Two matrices are not equal because the number of cells visible from a cell does not always equal the number of cells to which that cell is visible. Next, these two visibility grids are converted to friction surfaces. These surfaces are used as the input grids to the least-cost path procedure. To do this, a few adjustments must be made to create the friction surfaces suitable for calculating viewpaths that we wish to use. For this study, we have implemented a total of four viewpaths. Each of the four viewpaths requires different friction surfaces to be setup from viewgrids.

Does someone know how to create the viewgrids and covert them into friction surfaces?